# How to add tab or spaces in front of multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox, word-wrap

I can´t figure out, how could I get result like this:

Note : text
           multiple lines 
           some text more 
           and more text

In that code I get wrong answer like :

Note : text 
multiple lines 
some text more 
and more text

In textwrap I tried but it destroyed output text.

```
import tkinter as tk

# make file
try:  
    open('MyPyDict.txt')
except FileNotFoundError:
    open('MyPyDict.txt', 'w')


# button for text input
def insert():  
    note = entry_note.get()
    text = entry_defs.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    print(note + ' : ' + text + '\n')
    # f = open('MyPyDict.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    # f.write(note + ' : ' + text + '\n')

master = tk.Tk()  # program window
master.title('MyPyDict')
master.geometry('400x350')

# note label
label_note = tk.Label(master, text='Note', font=16)
label_note.place(x=5, y=20)

# Insert/Search label
label_text = tk.Label(master, text='Insert/Search', font=16)
label_text.place(x=5, y=55)

# for inserting and searching textbox
entry_defs = tk.Text(master, font=16, height=10, width=20)
entry_defs.place(x=120, y=55)

# note entry
entry_note = tk.Entry(master, font=16)
entry_note.place(x=120, y=20)

# insert button
button_insert = tk.Button(master, text='Insert', font=16, command=insert)
button_insert.place(x=252, y=250)

# search button
button_search = tk.Button(master, text='Search', font=16)
button_search.place(x=180, y=250)

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

As I now understand your question (based on your comment below), here is how it could be done with the help of the `textwrap` module.

Note this doesn't put tab characters in front of the lines, instead it puts a prefix string composed of space characters so they will line up. If you really want tab characters, set `prefix = '\t'` instead of what is shown.

```
import textwrap

# button for text input
def insert():
    note = entry_note.get() + ' : '
    text = note + entry_defs.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    textlines = text.splitlines(True)
    prefix = ' ' * len(note)
    formatted = textlines[0] + textwrap.indent(''.join(textlines[1:]), prefix)
    print(formatted)
    # f = open('MyPyDict.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    # f.write(formatted + '\n')
```

Comment: Yes I could use this solution. But if I print it, output first line could go little long and it isn´t very nice for eye. So I need solution where output text part starts in one column.

Comment: Eggii: In that case, you're effectively changing the question you posted.